# The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_22 was killed

Tags: android, android-studio, windows, adb, wsl

Cuando intento levantar mi emulador, sale el siguiente mensaje: "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_22 was killed."

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi computadora tiene las siguientes caracteristicas:

- AMD Ryzen 7 3700x 8-Core Processor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya hizo lo siguiente:
Mi Virtualización esta habilitada desde el BIOS.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien que paso por lo mismo...?

Comment: Fijate si esta bien configurado crea otro emulador si no.

Comment: Ya realice eso, borre mi emulador y lo volví a configurar, pero sigue dando lo mismo.

Comment: reiniciaste tu maquina?, puede ser algun error en ejecucion.